# Looking for a custom SDK with photo editing capabilities

Tags: ios, image-processing, photo, editing, aviary

I have a (academic) project, in which I have to develop a UI skeleton for a photo editing app, that provides basic UI functionality (like Aviary and such).

Purpose of the project is for me to explore and use iOS (view) object library.

Even though the nature of the project does not demand any photo editing functionality, I'd still like to integrate as many features as I could.

For that purpose I have been looking for photo editing SDKs, so far only one that stands out is the "Aviary iOS SDK".

As of now what I understand (correct me if I am wrong!) is that Aviary allows you to present its view-controller in your app, and then Aviary takes over and does all the stuff on its own. If that is the case, then Aviary is of no use to me, since the actual homework demands me to put the UI together myself. And I know that Aviary provides a SDK customizer as well; but not what I am looking for. I'd like for me to specify the operation I want and Aviary simply returning me the output image.

Due to this reason, I am looking for a SDK, that provides me with the all the major aviary-like photo editing features, but in code. So that I could interact with the API via my controller.

For example an interface like as follows would be of great use:

```
- (UIImage*) applyGrayScaleFilter: (UIImage*) image;
```

Answer (score 6):

You should consider Brad Larson's [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) - open source iOS framework for GPU-based image and video processing.

Comment: Could you please list down the major features offered by GPUImage.

Comment: You can find a precise breakdown within the [README](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#built-in-filters). You mainly have: Color adjustments (grayscaling, etc), Image Processing (cropping, blurring, etc), Blending and Visual Effects (pixellate, etc).

Comment: Thanks man! Wish I could +1 your response. Anyways you have provided me with a dimension.